# Using take on an iterator without copying

Tags: rust

I had to replace

```
let mut bo = vec![];
try!(o.read_to_end(&mut bo));
let mut bo = bo.into_iter();
let vs : Vec<_> = (&mut bo).take(BUFFER).collect();
try!(io::stdout().write(&vs));
```

with this

```
let mut bo = vec![];
try!(o.read_to_end(&mut bo));
let mut io = 0;
let next = min(bo.len(), io + BUFFER);
try!(io::stdout().write(&bo[io..next]));
```

Using a slice was more than twice as fast as copying data into a `Vec`. Is there a way to use `take(n)` without copying?

Answer (score 1):

[`Iterator::take`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) doesn't do any copying. Collecting the iterator into a vector, on the other hand, both allocates space and then moves items from the iterator into the collection.

Using a slice is the most idiomatic solution here. You have a contiguous range of bytes that you want to output in the vector, and slicing into that vector gives you an almost-free view into a range of those bytes.

Comment: I'm happy with using slices, but calculating the indices for the slice is error-prone.